# Azure mobile service custom API calling SQL SP multiple times

Tags: ios, sql, sql-server, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure mobile service with a custom API and it seems to be making multiple SQL calls.  When I look at the log, I am seeing multiple responses coming back from the SP.  Some of these are empty returns (no recordset), while one of them is communicating with the SP correctly and returning a recordset.

I know my iOS app is only calling the custom API once.

Here is the custom API:

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
    var mssql = request.service.mssql; 

    var params = [request.query.FirstName , 
    request.query.LastName , 
    request.query.DOB ,
    request.query.EmailAddress , 
    request.query.PhoneNumber , 
    request.query.FacilityID ,
    request.query.DiagnosisID, 
    request.query.GeneratedBy , 
    request.query.UserTypeID];

    console.log("processregistration params = '%j'", params);
    var sql = "exec MyStoredProcName ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?";
    mssql.query(sql, params, {
        success: function(results) {
            console.log("results = '%j'", results);
            // I had to put this in there to keep it from returning an empty recordset
            // back to my iOS app
            if (results.length > 0) {
                response.send(statusCodes.OK, results);
            }

        }        
    });
};
```

Here is the log:
[image: Console Log Screenshot]

I know the SP only produces one recordset and testing it directly produces a single recordset.  I have been able to band-aid it but putting in an if statement before the `response.send`.  I have never had to do that before.  Any ideas?

EDIT - Here is my SP (posted for carlosfigueira)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
/*

==========================================================================================
Author:         LJ Wilson
Create date:    2013-12-07
Description:    Processes a new (or existing) user registration
==========================================================================================

Revision History
Date            Initials    Comments
2013-12-07      LJW         Created
2013-12-18      LJW         Fixed issue with InvitationCodeID

*/
ALTER PROCEDURE [MyApp].[sp_Process_Registration]
    @FirstName VARCHAR(500) ,
    @LastName VARCHAR(500) ,
    @DOB DATETIME ,
    @EmailAddress VARCHAR(500) ,
    @PhoneNumber VARCHAR(25) ,
    @FacilityID INT ,
    @DiagnosisID INT ,
    @GeneratedBy NVARCHAR(500) ,
    @UserTypeID INT
AS 

DECLARE @Timestamp AS DATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

DECLARE @ExistingUserID AS INT = ( SELECT   ID
                                   FROM     MyApp.Users
                                   WHERE    UserTypeID = @UserTypeID
                                            AND EmailAddress = @EmailAddress
                                            AND LastName = @LastName
                                 )

DECLARE @EmailAddressInUse AS INT = ( SELECT    COUNT(ID)
                                      FROM      MyApp.Users
                                      WHERE     EmailAddress = @EmailAddress
                                    )  

IF @ExistingUserID IS NULL 
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRAN
        INSERT  INTO MyApp.Users
                ( LoginName ,
                  FriendlyName ,
                  JoinDate ,
                  PhoneNumber ,
                  EmailAddress ,
                  UserTypeID ,
                  IsActive ,
                  FacilitiesListID ,
                  AllowTexting ,
                  AllowEmail ,
                  AllowCalls ,
                  AllowAPNS ,
                  ImagePath ,
                  ShowImage ,
                  LastUpdatedBy ,
                  LastUpdatedOn ,
                  FirstName ,
                  LastName ,
                  DOB
                )
        VALUES  ( @EmailAddress , -- LoginName - nvarchar(250)
                  NULL , -- FriendlyName - nvarchar(500)
                  @Timestamp , -- JoinDate - datetime
                  @PhoneNumber , -- PhoneNumber - nvarchar(50)
                  @EmailAddress , -- EmailAddress - nvarchar(500)
                  @UserTypeID , -- UserTypeID - smallint
                  1 , -- IsActive - bit
                  NULL , -- FacilitiesListID - int
                  NULL , -- AllowTexting - bit
                  1 , -- AllowEmail - bit
                  NULL , -- AllowCalls - bit
                  1 , -- AllowAPNS - bit
                  NULL , -- ImagePath - nvarchar(1000)
                  NULL , -- ShowImage - bit
                  @GeneratedBy , -- LastUpdatedBy - nvarchar(500)
                  @TimeStamp , -- LastUpdatedOn - datetime
                  @FirstName , -- FirstName - varchar(500)
                  @LastName ,  -- LastName - varchar(500)
                  @DOB -- DOB - datetime
                )
        COMMIT TRAN
        SET @ExistingUserID = ( SELECT  @@IDENTITY
                              )  
    END  

BEGIN
    DECLARE @InvitationCode AS VARCHAR(50) = ( SELECT   dbo.fnc_GenInvitationCode(@EmailAddress,
                                                              @FacilityID,
                                                              @DiagnosisID)
                                             )
    INSERT  INTO MyApp.InvitationCodes
            ( InvitationCode ,
              UserID ,
              FacilityID ,
              InvitationGeneratedOn ,
              GeneratedBy ,
              DiagnosisIdentifier ,
              InvitationActive

            )
    VALUES  ( @InvitationCode , -- InvitationCode - nvarchar(50)
              @ExistingUserID , -- UserID - int
              @FacilityID , -- FacilityID - int
              @Timestamp , -- InvitationGeneratedOn - datetime
              @GeneratedBy , -- GeneratedBy - nvarchar(500)
              @DiagnosisID , -- DiagnosisIdentifier - int
              NULL  -- InvitationActive - bit

            )
END
DECLARE @InvitationCodeID AS INT = ( SELECT ID
                                     FROM   MyApp.InvitationCodes
                                     WHERE  InvitationCode = @InvitationCode
                                            AND InvitationGeneratedOn = @Timestamp
                                   )

INSERT  INTO MyApp.FacilitiesList
        ( UserID ,
          InvitationCodeID ,
          FacilityID ,
          AddedOn ,
          AddedBy

        )
VALUES  ( @ExistingUserID , -- UserID - int
          @InvitationCodeID , -- InvitationCodeID - int
          @FacilityID , -- FacilityID - int
          @Timestamp , -- AddedOn - datetime
          @GeneratedBy  -- AddedBy - nvarchar(500)

        )

SELECT  @InvitationCode AS InvitationCode ,
        @EmailAddressInUse AS EmailAddressInUse ,
        @ExistingUserID AS ExistingUserID


GO
```

Comment: This is a bug for which we already implemented a fix, and it should be corrected soon. It won't happen before next year, though, since we won't do any deployments in the weeks of Christmas and new year (unless there's a security or a major blocking issue, and you seem to have a workaround for your problem).

Comment: Could you also please post your stored procedure so we can verify that the fix we have would work in your case as well? Thanks!

Comment: Added SQL for SP.  Thx!  BTW - I assume you are part of the Azure engineering team?  If so, do you know Josh Twist?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I work on that team, and Josh is a friend here - one of the best we have here, I'd say.

Comment: Awesome.  Shared a taxi with Josh in Dallas last year at CocoaConf.  Great guy and the main reason I am using Azure now.

Comment: Actually the issue we're fixing isn't the same as yours. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having is that your stored procedure is executing lots of intermediate operations (query for existing user id, query for e-mail address in use, etc.), and by default all of those operations are returned as result sets by the SQL server, which is why you're seeing those empty result sets before the "real" one.

You can use the `SET NOCOUNT ON` statement in your stored procedure, and that will effectively remove those intermediate SQL executions from the list of result sets which is returned to the `mssql.query` function. Your SPROC would look like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [carlosfigueira].[sp_Process_Registration]
    @FirstName VARCHAR(500) ,
    @LastName VARCHAR(500) ,
    @DOB DATETIME ,
    @EmailAddress VARCHAR(500) ,
    @PhoneNumber VARCHAR(25) ,
    @FacilityID INT ,
    @DiagnosisID INT ,
    @GeneratedBy NVARCHAR(500) ,
    @UserTypeID INT
AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Timestamp AS DATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

-- rest of the stored proc code is the same
```

Once you add that statement, the callback passed to `mssql.query` will only be invoked once.

Comment: Doh!  I know what NOCOUNT does, I just didn't think about how the API was interpreting those messages.  Thanks!